# Understand BINDER_VM_SIZE in Android source code

Tags: android, linux-kernel

In file `framework/native/libs/binder/ProcessState.cpp`

Why is `BINDER_VM_SIZE` set to 1M-8k?

```
#define BINDER_VM_SIZE ((1*1024*1024) - (4096 *2))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not this value initially, you can find that(from git commit log) it's first value is

```
#define BINDER_VM_SIZE (1*1024*1024)
```

Then someone change this value to

```
#define BINDER_VM_SIZE ((1*1024*1024) - (4096 *2))
```

with the following commit message:

> Modify the binder to request 1M - 2 pages instead of 1M.  The backing
>   store in the kernel requires a guard page, so 1M allocations fragment
>   memory very badly.  Subtracting a couple of pages so that they fit in
>   a power of two allows the kernel to make more efficient use of its
>   virtual address space.

I myself don't fully understand this message，so I just paste it here hope it may help your understanding!